# Mathematica 10 loads too long time

Tags: performance-tuning, bugs

After starting Mathematica 10 it hangs for about a minute before becoming operational.

Internet connectivity is disabled.

Start screen is disabled.

What should I do?

P.S. Opening any help page also takes a lot of time with a messagebox "Formatting notebook contents".

Comment: fyi, some discussion related here  http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/291612?p_p_auth=CDjlQwC5 "Can my start up time for Mathematica 10 be decreased?" do not know if it is the same issue as you are having.

Comment: It takes about 3 sec for V10 and 2 sec for V9 on my old laptop with Core 2 Duo and Linux. Of course, it isn't a magic, I installed SSD as a second disk (instead DVD). So disk speed plays a crucial role. May be you can [preload](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preload_(software)) some Mathematica libraries to RAM.

Comment: @ybeltukov Mathematica 9 loaded just quick on the same computer.

Comment: @Anixx, what is your operating system?

Comment: @ybeltukov AMD A6-4400@3200 GHz, 4 GB RAM

Comment: @Anixx I mean Windows/Linux/MacOS

Comment: @ybeltukov Windows 7.